# Django Network Error (tcp_error)

Tags: python, django, apache

I am using the django-admin, but i keep getting this response header:

```
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Tue, 20 Jun 2017 09:53:32 GMT
ETag:"56138860-0"
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

and

```
Request URL:http://52.43.93.333/real-admin-interface-2017/mooimom_id/product/85/change/?_changelist_filters=o%3D-1
Request Method:POST
Status Code:503 Service Unavailable
Remote Address:52.43.93.333:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

and this frontend output

```
Network Error (tcp_error) 

A communication error occurred: "Operation timed out"
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems 
preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.

For assistance, contact your network support team.
```

I am using Apache, Ubuntu and AWS. My RDS is external AWS machine (not the same EC2 machine). I have already changed the Timeout to 999 and KeepAliveTimeout to 15 in the apache.conf, but i still keep getting this error only for few objects that have a lot of data to save.

My mod_WSGI 000-default.conf settings in apache.conf for apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
Alias /media/ /var/www/mooimom_django/media_root/
Alias /static/ /var/www/mooimom_django/static/

<Directory /var/www/mooimom_django/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/mooimom_django/media_root>
Require all granted
</Directory>

 WSGIDaemonProcess mooimom_django python-path=/var/www/mooimom_django:/var/www/mooimom_django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
 WSGIProcessGroup mooimom_django
 WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mooimom_django/mooimom_django/wsgi.py

 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: How you are running appication server(behind apache) ?

Comment: i updated the question to add the mod_WSGI setting